# Excel vba website

Tags: excel, vba

```
<td class="sell"> 
<button class="btnSell btnSell-highlight" title="Sell @ 1.3" id="btnSell-group_a.5c653e67-61dc-4e0c-97dc-ca44476dfb76.manual.adecf17a-35f2-4ac4-b337-bbfbb5e42ec4">1.3</button>
</td>
```

Hi, I am new to using Excel VBA. My aim is to get the decimal value of 1.3.
I tried extracting this value through the following code:

```
Sub ExtractLastValue()

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Navigate ("Enter webiste name")

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.readystate = 4

MsgBox objIE.document.getElementsByclassname("sell")(0).getElementsbyid("btnSell-group_a.5c653e67-61dc-4e0c-97dc-ca44476dfb76.manual.adecf17a-35f2-4ac4-b337-bbfbb5e42ec4").innertext

End Sub
```

However, once I run the code an error:

Error Time 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell `.getElementsByclassname("sell")(0)` is completely redundant. Why don't you just retrieve the element you want to extract text from directly with `GetElementById`? Also notice it's `GetElementById`, **not** `GetElementsById`, which explains why your code wasn't automatically properly cased by the IDE.

**Edit #1**

This should work:

```
MsgBox objIE.document.getElementbyid("btnSell-group_a.5c653e67-61dc-4e0c-97dc-ca44476dfb76.manual.adecf17a-35f2-4ac4-b337-bbfbb5e42ec4").innertext
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot I managed to get rid of the error by changing the following statement 
`MsgBox objIE.document.getElementbyid("btnSell-group_a.fbf6e724-e133-4b6d- a86b-121d1c8fdf63.manual.76e7c687-10c7-485c-8672-5c7c9fdd0c57").innertext`

However, a pop up window with no integer pops up. –

Comment: This indicates you haven't retrieved the right element. Check for spelling mistakes. The id ends with 2ec4. Your code in the previous comment doesn't.